# Postal code using structures

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I'm trying to make a a structure that stores postal codes but I receive this error: "c:15:11: error: assignment to expression with array type
  h->array = malloc(sizeof(PostalCode)*size);"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct PostalCode
{
    int size;
    char *array[5];
} PostalCode;

void main()
{
    int size = 5;
    PostalCode *h = malloc(sizeof(PostalCode));
    h->size = size;
    h->array = malloc(sizeof(PostalCode)*size);
}
```

Comment: Since `array` is an array of pointers to characters, not `PostalCode`, why are you multiplying `sizeof(PostalCode) * size` when you try to allocate it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The structure already contains an array of 5 pointers as its data member

```
typedef struct PostalCode
{
    int size;
    char *array[5];
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

So you need not to allocate it.

If you want to use this array to store for example 5 object of type `PostalCode`
(though in this case it would be better if the array has type `PostalCode *array[5]`) then you can write

```
for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
{ 
    h->array[i] = malloc( sizeof( PostalCode ) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to allocate `array`, it's an array, not a pointer. But you do need to allocate memory for each element.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    h->array[i] = malloc(size);
}
```