# How to solve the error: assignment to expression with array type

Tags: c

I am asked to create a `carinfo` structure and a `createcarinfo()` function in order to make a database. But when trying to allocate memory for the arrays of the brand and model of the car, the terminal points out two errors.

For:

```
newCar->brand =(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(brand) + 1));
newCar->model = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(model) + 1));
```

it says that there is an error: assignment to expression with array type and an arrow pointing to the equal sign.

```
struct carinfo_t {

    char brand[40];
    char model[40];
    int year;
    float value;



};

struct carinfo_t *createCarinfo(char *brand, char *model, int year, float value){

   struct carinfo_t *newCar;
   newCar=(struct carinfo_t*)malloc( sizeof( struct carinfo_t ) );

    if (newCar){
         newCar->brand =(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(brand) + 1));
        newCar->model = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(model) + 1));
       strcpy(newCar->brand, brand);
        strcpy(newCar->model, model);
        //newCar->brand=brand;
        //newCar->model=model;
        newCar->year=year;
        newCar->value=value;
    }
    return newCar;


};
```

Comment: Please don't take this the wrong way, but it seems you need to go over your class notes, text books or tutorials a little more. Arrays are not pointers, the compiler will already allocate memory for them, and you don't need to do it yourself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Postal code using structures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33927488/postal-code-using-structures)

Comment: OT:  when calling any of the heap allocation functions: `malloc` `calloc` `realloc`, 1) the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  2) the expression: `sizeof(char)`  is defined in the standard as 1.  Multiplying anything by 1 has no effect.  Suggest removing that expression.  3) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring the fixed size arrays in the struct.

Maybe you want to do this:

```
struct carinfo_t {

char *brand;
char *model;
int year;
float value;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Two things.

1. In your code, `brand` and `model` are already of array type, they have memory allocated to them based on their size (`char [40]`) on declaration. You need not allocate any memory using the allocator function (unlike pointers, on other hand).
2. You cannot assign to an array type. Array types are not suitable for a LHS argument for an assignment operator.This is what basically throws the error you see, but if you adhere to #1, you'll never reach here.

Comment: "... if you adhere to #` ..."? I assume that's a typo, but I don't know what it's supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you may have mistyped the definition of your `struct`.
Maybe change it to something like this:

```
struct carinfo_t {
    char* brand;
    char* model;
    int year;
    float value;
};
```

The reason you are getting that error is because you are trying to assign the pointer returned by malloc to an array. That won't work. You should instead be storing the pointer returned by `malloc` in a `char*`.